# Crystal Reports / Progress DB Pivot Data (Transpose)

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I arrange my table data...

```
ID    Name
1     A1
2     A2
3     A3
4     A5
```

...like this in my report?

```
A1    A2    A3   A5
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Details Section Header, then pick *Section Expert*.

In the *Select Details* section check *Format with Multiple Columns*